# Iterating overJSON key starting with '$' in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display key value of a json object by iterating over it.
Here is my code

```
    <html ng-app>
     <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script src="script.js"></script>
     </head>

     <body ng-init='x = {"$xy":"boost-combinations@$q,article,false,10"}'>
      <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in x">{{k}} : {{v}}</li>
       <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
     </body>
   </html>
```

I just want to display as $xy : boost-combinations@$q,article,false,10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possibile. All $ and $$ characters are ignored. If you see ngRepeat.js of angular sources you can read this information.

```
 *`ngRepeat` will silently *ignore* object keys starting with `$`, because
 *   it's a prefix used by Angular for public (`$`) and private (`$$`) properties.
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, angular ignores keys starting with '$' as a default behavior.

I guess the most straight-forward way to override this is to implement your own function that creates an array from object and iterate that:

```
 <body ng-init='x = {"$xy":"boost-combinations@$q,article,false,10"}'>
  <li ng-repeat="item in fix(x)">{{item.k}} : {{item.v}}</li>
```

and in a controller

```
function fix(x) {
  return Object.keys(x).map(function(k) {
    return { k: k, v: x[k] };
  });
}
```

Comment: It gives me error of maximum digest iteration has reached and then aborts execution:angular.js: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: well, you should (for performance as well) do this in a watch only when x changes => `$scope.$watch('x', function(oldV, newV) { if (oldV !== newV { $scope.xFixed = fix(newV) ... ` then you iterate over 'xFixed' not directly applying the function

Answer (score 0):

This simply worked for me -

```
<div ng-init='y = [{ "$xy": "boost-combinations@$q,article,false,10" }]'>
   <div ng-repeat="(k, v) in y">
      {{v}}
   </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-init='y = { "$xy": "boost-combinations@$q,article,false,10" }'>
   {{y}}
</div>
```